# Change Machine Math & Logic Errors

Tags: java, math, double

I've posted this program once before but realized I was overthinking it by adding loops and what not. I've paired it down a bit but still running into problems. The program is supposed to be a change machine. After the user inputs price, the program should round it up to the nearest dollar then output how much change will be dispensed and a count of which coins. The output is completely wrong at this point. I'm very new to programming and I'm at a loss.

```
package changemachine;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.*;

public class Main 
{

  public static void main(String[] args) 
   {   
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter Purchase Price: ");

    double price = scan.nextDouble();

    int newPrice = (int)(price*100);

    int paid = (int)(newPrice+1);

    int change = (int)(paid - newPrice);

    int quarters = (int)(change/25);
    int dimes = (int)((change%25)/10);
    int nickels = (int)((change%25%10)/5);
    int pennies = (int) (change%25%10%5);

    System.out.println("Dispensing: " + quarters + " Quarters,"
          + dimes + "Dimes," + nickels + "Nickels," 
          + pennies + "Pennies.");

    System.out.println("Program written by Ashley ");
 }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with it? You set `change` to be one cent more than what the user entered, and it always tells me that one cent will be dispensed.

Answer (score 2):

(Once `newPrice` is an `int`, you can stop casting every line.)  Instead of chaining `%` together, it would be more readable (and less error prone) to subtract off the values you've found:

```
change -= 25*quarters;
dimes = change / 10;
change -= 10*dimes;
nickels = change / 5;
change -= 5*nickels;
pennies = change;
```

Comment: the % are there to take out the quarters and only find how many times the remainder is divisible by 10..without them wouldn't it show many many of each coin the change is divisible by?

Comment: The `-=` takes care of that.  The first line is equivalent to `change = change - 25*quarters`.

Comment: By the way, you should use rounding to convert the number of cents to an int.  Casting with `(int)` could leave you a penny short because of floating point arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would help you to understand if you would go through the code by hand and think about what price, newprice, paid, and change are.

newprice is the price round down to the lower dollar.
paid is the cost of the item.
change is the amount you paid minus the cost converted into an integer number of pennies.

```
package changemachine;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.*;

public class Main 
{

  public static void main(String[] args) 
   {   
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter Purchase Price: ");

    double price = scan.nextDouble();

            int newPrice = (int)(price);

            int paid = (int)(newPrice+1);

            int change = (int)((paid - price) * 100);

    int quarters = (int)(change/25);
    int dimes = (int)((change%25)/10);
    int nickels = (int)((change%25%10)/5);
    int pennies = (int) (change%25%10%5);

    System.out.println("Dispensing: " + quarters + " Quarters,"
          + dimes + "Dimes," + nickels + "Nickels," 
          + pennies + "Pennies.");

    System.out.println("Program written by Ashley ");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If instruction `int paid= (int)(newPrice+1) ;` is supposed to be rounding to next dollar, then it should be: `int paid= ( newPrice + 99 ) / 100 * 100 ;`  You don't need to convert to `(int)` when both operands are already `int`s.  Makes your program slightly illegible.  Later, after obtaining the number of quarters by quarters= change / 25 ;`(that's correct in your program), you can reduce the amount from`change`with`change-= quarters * 25 ;`.

This makes calculating `dimes` exactly the same as `quarters`, just that using `10` instead of `25`.  Don't forget reducing the dimes from the pending `change` again with `change-= dimes * 10 ;`.  You can repeat the process with `nickels` and the remaining `change` will be `pennies`.

If you have any doubt, use a debugger or output each intermediate result with `System.out`.  You can always delete them later once you understand your program's behavior.

Comment: Don't you think `Math.ceil(price) * 100;` would be more intuitive and easier to read than `(newPrice+99) / 100 * 100;` ?

Comment: In fact, sorry Mario, but if I saw that in production code I would get mad at you lol. You should say `((newPrice+99) / 100) * 100;` just to clarify what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Not sure.  I just tried to change the OP's way of thinking as little as possible when not making a big mistake.  IOW, I tried to "pick my battles".  In a real world application requiring decimal precision I would be using `BigDecimal`s expressing dollars and not cents.

Comment: @ryvantage  I won't answer comments expressed in that way.  We can argue respectfully, but "mad"s, "lol"s are out of place.  You are right that `( ( newPrice + 99 ) / 100) * 100` is clearer than `( newPrice + 99 ) / 100 * 100`.

Comment: @ryvantage  If I had time (and the OP the experience to understand it), I would have explained the risks of floating point and why is better to use `BigDecimal` in these cases.  But the OP needs to go through some previous steps first.

Comment: Agreed, @MarioRossi, there are a lot of concerns to be had. The "lol" was to lighten the fact that I said "mad" because I was trying to be constructively critical without being offensive. I was initially stumped trying to figure out why your code worked, only to realize I was forgetting programming OOO. And, I figured, if I'm stumped the OP would probably be stumped as well because they probably don't know OOO. So, I thought to give you some constructive criticism. But apparently I'm just offending everyone in this thread... *tugs collar*

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made Java choose what coins I must pay with.

```
    int temp = m;
    int quarterCoin = 25;
    int x = m/quarterCoin;
    m=m-x*quarterCoin;

    int dimeCoin = 10;
    int z = m/dimeCoin;
    m=m-z*dimeCoin;

    int nickelCoin = 5;
    int y = m/nickelCoin;
    m=m-y*nickelCoin;

    int pennyCoin = 1;
    int w = m/pennyCoin;
    m=m-w*pennyCoin;
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of giving you the answer/solution to your homework, I am going to help you figure out how to figure it out. :)

In order to adequately debug your software and troubleshoot what's going on, **you need to know what your variables are doing.** There are two methods:

1. Attach a debugger - Most IDEs will come with a debugger that will help you accomplish this.
2. Print out your variables to the console. This is my preferred method. Me and debuggers never have gotten along well together. :)

So, here is what I would do if I were trying to figure your program out:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Change {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

//        System.out.println("Enter Purchase Price: ");

        double price = 5.65d;//scan.nextDouble();

        int newPrice = (int) (price * 100);
        System.out.println("newPrice: " + newPrice);

        int paid = (int) (newPrice + 1);
        System.out.println("paid: " + paid);

        int change = (int) (paid - newPrice);
        System.out.println("change: " + change);

        int quarters = (int) (change / 25);
        int dimes = (int) ((change % 25) / 10);
        int nickels = (int) ((change % 25 % 10) / 5);
        int pennies = (int) (change % 25 % 10 % 5);

        System.out.println("Dispensing: " + quarters + " Quarters,"
                + dimes + "Dimes," + nickels + "Nickels,"
                + pennies + "Pennies.");

        System.out.println("Program written by Ashley ");
    }
}
```

(Note: Instead of utilizing the scanner, I just manually entered "5.65" into the `price` variable just to save time)

Which produces the output:

```
newPrice: 565
paid: 566
change: 1
Dispensing: 0 Quarters,0Dimes,0Nickels,1Pennies.
Program written by Ashley
```

So, now you can see what your program is doing wrong. Can you spot it?

Comment: Is it that it is only rounding up to 1 cent rather than to the nearest dollar? maybe I should keep the price and paid amounts doubles until after I've found the change then multiply by 100?

Comment: The tone of your answer is patronizing.  Most disgusting to read.

Comment: If that is true, @VeronicaCornejo it is simply because of an inability to adequately express myself through text. The spirit of my answer was to teach the OP how to learn to program, rather than giving her the straight answer. I was honestly not trying to be condescending or patronizing. In fact, I was eager to see responses to my answer because I genuinely felt it was a good answer with noble intent. My sincerest apologies for the miscommunication.

Comment: Yes, @AshleyTaylor, the error is in the line `int paid = (int) (newPrice + 1);`. I would change that line to `int paid = (int) Math.ceil(price) * 100;` as long as you are allowed to use the `java.​lang.Math` library in your assignment.

Comment: @ryvantage Sorry for the delayed response. Your guidance helped tremendously. I didn't feel you were patronizing at all. I needed someone to walk me through figuring out my mistakes because I sincerely want to learn this. I ended up using the math library you suggested and beyond a few other silly math problems I got it to work. Thanks again for your help!